# Actualizar datos de FlatList graphQL sin perdida de datos

Tags: react-native, graphql

Estoy desarrollando una app en **React Native**, usando la pokeapi para sacar una lista de pokemons.
Cuando llego al loadMore() se actualizan los Pokemons pero no se conservan los anteriores.
He intentado crear un estado de Pokemons pero me salen demasiados rerenders, si teneis visión para posibles soluciones lo agradezco!

```
export const POKEMON = gql` query samplePokeAPIquery ($offset: Int) {
  pokemon_v2_pokemon(limit: 21,offset: $offset){
    name
    id
    pokemon_v2_pokemontypes {
      pokemon_v2_type {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Esta es mi consulta de GraphQL, cuando se llama a loadMore se cambia el setOffset y se cargan los 21 siguientes pokemon, el problema es que pierdo a los anteriores.

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {



const [offst, setOffset] = useState(0)
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState('pi')
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  const loadMore = () => {
    setOffset(offst+21)
    setPokemons(pokemons+data);
  }

  console.log("Home")
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(POKEMON, {variables: { "offset": offst }});
  const renderData = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <PokemonList 
      item = { item }
      navigation={ navigation }
      />
    )
  }

  return (

<View style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput
    value={text}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    placeholder='Busca un Pokémon'
    maxLength={12}
    />
  {loading ? <Text>Cargando</Text>
    :
    <FlatList
      data={pokemons.pokemon_v2_pokemon}
      keyExtractor={(pokemon) => pokemon.id}
      ListHeaderComponent={() => <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18, margin: 30 }}>Toca en un pokemon de la Pokédex y mira su información!</Text>}
      numColumns={3}
      contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      onEndReached={()=>{

        loadMore()
      }}
      renderItem={renderData}
    />
  }</View>
```

Comment: Puede ser un almacenamiento en `localStorage` con `limit` como intervalo de paginación entre subconsultas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice al final fue usar UseEffect para guardar los datos en otra variable e irlos acumulando con el uso de spread(...)

```
useEffect( () => {
if(data && Object.keys(data)?.length>0){
  setPokemons([...pokemons,...data.pokemon_v2_pokemon])
}
 


}, [data])
```

Se comprueba si los datos han llegado para setear los pokemon.

Comment: Si pudieras agregar la pieza de código donde hiciste la propagación